# Programmatically get storage directory of an app knowing its package name

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am developing an app which needs access to the directory of an android app (whether internal or external storage) where its files are stored (such as media), starting from its package name.
Foe example:
Say my app wants to acces media files of WhatsApp. I know that WhatsApp package name is "com.whatsapp", and i know that whatsapp is currently installed. How can i find its media folder inside the file system?

I've already searched a lot and I couldn't find a satisfying answer. Many of the answers were about finding the .apk and stuff like that.
I thought about a possible solution was using PackageManager (as suggested in the answers about .apk) but I don't feel this is the right way to get what I want.

Comment: Do you mean the folder for the installed app under /data? I do not think you have access to that from another app.

Comment: You'd trying to access the private data store of *another* app? On unrooted phones?

Comment: Yes, for example i want to display a gallery with pics stored under the WhatsApp/Media folder. But I can't figure out how to identify where the Media folder is located into the device.

Comment: fiipi, did you get the way to store image in application folder?

Comment: No, I didn't manage to solve this task. Anyway I've abandoned my original project, so I didn't look for a workaround neither.